How do authorize with Identity Server and Azure Active Directory?
It is necessary to make authorization through these systems. Leave the login and password through the Server Identity page, and the process itself through AAD.
I did so. The token from AAD is returned to me, but I cannot enter the Angular project
Client:
new Client
{
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
    AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 300,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    ClientId = MyClients.Portal,
    ClientName = "ortal client",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret(MySecrets.Portal.Sha256()) },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RequirePkce = false,

    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = coreSettings.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetimeInSeconds,

    RedirectUris =
    {
        $"{coreSettings.Portal}/auth-callback",
        $"{coreSettings.Portal}/silent-refresh.html"
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris =
    {
        coreSettings.IdentityServer
    },
    AllowedCorsOrigins =
    {
        coreSettings.ApiService,
        coreSettings.Portal
    },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        StandardScopes.OpenId,
        StandardScopes.Profile,
        MyScopes.Api,
    }
}

Identity Server login method:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenet ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        ClientId = "ClientId",
        ClientSecret = "ClientSecret",
        Scope = "openid profile User.Read",
        UserName = model.Email,
        Password = model.Password
    });

    if (!tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { token = tokenResponse.AccessToken });
        return Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
}

[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string token)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var userInfoResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
    if (!userInfoResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid token");
    }

    var userInfo = await userInfoResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserInfo>();

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new IdentityServerUser(userInfo.Id.ToString())
    {
        DisplayName = userInfo.DisplayName,
        AdditionalClaims = new List<Claim> { new(JwtClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Mail ?? userInfo.UserPrincipalName) }
    });

    return Redirect(_coreSettings.Portal);
}

Normal authorization through the identity server without AAD worked and if removed - it works. Authorization also works if you add a button to log in via AAD, but I need the login to be via the login and password processed by the identity server.
Maybe I don't understand and do something incorrectly, because I'm new to this authorization.
Thanks for all the suggestions

Why are you using Identity Server and Active Directory? Should be either or.

@GHDevOps The entire project uses the identity server, but there is a task that access for one portal have be transferred to AAD. The purpose of this: the employee left, the account was deleted and access was lost

You have two different tokens from two different providers. Is the AAD client talking to any of the other Identity Server clients? If so, in your AAD client, if you're using OIDC, you may be able to intercept the call in one of the event callbacks and call Identity Server to get the other token. It's complete overkill and you'll have a nightmare refreshing if you're using code flow.

@GHDevOps, AAD does not talk other client

Then that client will have to use AAD user flow to sign in/out. OIDC middleware should do the trick. You can make the AAD redirect look similar to the Identity Server redirect.

@GHDevOps, Could you give an example?
